# c# WinForm, I cant manage to get the info typed in my text boxes to be added to the list box

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a list box that can have books added/removed by the user, I am using four text boxes for the info to be inserted to the list box. also its seems like somethings is getting printed in the list box once i type in the textboxes but nothing is displayed, as i am a ble to click and select in side the list box

```
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   listBoxBooks.Items.Add(textBoxTitle);
   listBoxBooks.Items.Add(textBoxAuthor);
   listBoxBooks.Items.Add(textBoxISBN);
   listBoxBooks.Items.Add(textBoxPrice);
}

private void buttonRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void textBoxTitle_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Console.ReadLine();
}

private void listBoxBooks_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Console.WriteLine("");
```

Comment: is textBoxTitle a string or the textBox object?

Comment: To add an item to `ListBox` use `listBox1.Add(textBox1.Text)`. But it seems `ListBox` is not suitable for your requirement if you want to show more than one field for a `Book`. Currently you are adding different field of a book as different items of `ListBox`, while all field of a book should be together. You can create a `Book` class and set properties of book, then add the book to `ListBox` or a `DataGridView`.

Comment: textchanged event is not useful for this. try `Leave` event. also where do you add text to list?

Comment: @Johan its a textBox Object

Comment: @Badiparmagi I have 4 textBoxes above the list to add text to the list

Comment: Then read @RezaAghaei 's comment :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys kinda pointing towards the right way but, @RezaAghaei by the book class and set properties, do you mean somthing like this:         public class Books
        {
            string title;
            string author;
            int isbn;
            int price;
        }

Comment: @Mr.Ak I posted an example for you,

Comment: Would recommend using WPF instead. Winforms is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

To add an item to `ListBox` use `listBox1.Add(textBox1.Text)`. But it seems `ListBox` is not suitable for your requirement if you want to show more than one field for a book. Currently you are adding different field of a book as different items of ListBox, while all field of a book should be together. You can create a `Book` class and set properties of book, then add the book to `ListBox` or a `DataGridView`

**Example**

1- You can create a class like this:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public strain Author {get; set;}
    public string ISBN {get ;set;}
    public int Price {get; set;}
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} - {1}", Name, Author);
    }
}
```

2- Then define a binding list to hold books. Define this member at form level:

```
BindingList<Book> books = new BindingList<Book>();
```

3- In `Load` event of `Form` or in constructor, after `InitializeComponent`, set the `books` as `DataSource` of your `DataGridView` or your `ListBox`:

```
booksDataGridView.DataSource = books;
//booksListBox.DataSource = books;
```

4- Then by click on your button first create an instance of `Book` class and add it to `books` list. It will be shown in `ListBox` or `DataGridView` immediately:

```
var book = new Book();
book.Name = nameTextBox.Text;
book.Author = authorTextBox.Text;
book.ISBN = isbnTextBox.Text;
book.Price = int.Parse(priceTextBox.Text);
books.Add(book);
```

Comment: this is the way forward, but once the class and all the other parts of the code is added, i ran the program, but nothing way being displayed inside the listbox. is this the correct code for it to be displayed:    private void listBoxBooks_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }

Comment: sorry above may be a bit confusing, i still basically have, Console.WriteLine(""); inside the ListBox method

Comment: Follow the instructions in the answer. I didn't say anything about handling listbox events.

Comment: You can accept an answer by click on check mark near the answer. Also when you accept an answer, it would be great if you also vote for the answer by click on up arrow near the post. It's not compulsory at all, but it's common, reasonable and recommended. While you can accept only one answer, you can upvote as many answer as you find useful, including the accepted one. For more information about how does accepting answers work see this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow).